# Profiling with gprof points to trivial function that is never called

Tags: c++, profiling, gprof

So, I have some code that I am trying to speed up.  Some relevant notes about this program:

1) I've commented out all the I/O

2) I've turned off multi-threading for these purposes `export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1`

3) No recursion

Now, I run the code and gprof tells me that it spends 87% of its time in `getGamma`

```
 %   cumulative   self              self     total
 time   seconds   seconds    calls  us/call  us/call  name
 87.49     20.69    20.69  3125353     6.62     6.62  Alkali::getGamma(double, double)
```

(This is the very first line of the profile, so I *think* I am reading this correctly.  `gprof2dot` produces and image with `getGamma` in bright red so I'm probably right.)

The problem is that `getGamma` is basically a stub:

```
double Alkali::getGamma(double tau, double laser_power) {
  double gamma = (1.0 / tau);
  return gamma;
}
```

And when I `grep` on `getGamma` I only get the definition and one call in a setup routine.  Yep, adding a print statement confirms that this trivial function is only called once.

So what is fooling `gprof`? Among other compiler flags, I'm using `-O3`.  Let me know if you need any more info and thanks in advance.

Comment: it is called `3125353` according to report, not once.

Comment: Lots of people say "only profile optimized code". I, for one, disagree. But what's more, *gprof* does not stand up to critical scrutiny. There are very few posts where people actually understand *gprof* output. Check the comments on [*this post*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31794197/23771).

Comment: @Jarod42: It cannot possibly be called that many times.  I add a print statement and I see the print statement exactly once, yet `gprof` still reports 3 million calls.  This agrees with `grep`.

Comment: @fenkerbb Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I was reading up on the limitations of profiling and I'm intrigued by your question.